# Input sources missing

Tags: keyboard

All my input sources have disappeared.

I use Finnish, Japanese and Korean keyboards. For language switcher next clock on top menu-bar it shows "(NULL)" and "(NULL)" for Hiragana and Hangul input methods.

Other input sources like English are fine and still in place.

How can I re-install these?

[image: No Japanese input]
[image: No Korean input]
[image: These are all ok]

Answer (score 1):

Restart the computer, hold SHIFT before the apple logo show up, this will boot the Mac in safe mode, which will disable all other applications that are not required to start your Mac.  Note that this will take a few minutes. After this, try to locate the Input you need, it should be there.

If that fails, try the [fix suggested by Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203221).

If this fails, create a new Account.

祝你好运！！ (Good Luck!!)

Comment: Sure, but this may not be maintained on the next boot not in Safe Mode.

Answer (score 0):

System Preferences -> Language & Region -> Preferred Languages

Click on the <kbd>+</kbd> button to add a language.

Let us know if this worked? :)

Comment: Hi, these are all ok: http://i.imgur.com/0G8hL8A.png - All the input sources (keyboards) are missing.

Comment: @koreanname01 Set up a new user account and see if you have the same problem when logged into that.

Comment: @TomGewecke work on guest account, but not for my own.

Comment: @koreanname01 That probably indicates a broken .plist in Home/Library/Preferences.